# replace in one factor by another factor (inside dataframe)

Tags: r, vector, replace

I have two factors and they do not have the same number of levels, but I would like to use one factor to replace values in the other factor inside a data-frame based on the name and the order of the factors.

My data looks like this,

```
x <- factor(c("one", "two", "three", "two", "three"))
y <- factor(c(NA, "foo", NA, "bar", NA))

(df <- data.frame(x, y))

      x    y
1   one <NA>
2   two  foo
3 three <NA>
4   two  bar
5 three <NA>
```

and this is where I would like to end up,

```
      x    y     z
1   one <NA>   one
2   two  foo   foo
3 three <NA> three
4   two  bar   bar
5 three <NA> three
```

Should I convert the factors to a character vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `levels(z) <- c(levels(y), levels(x))` so that z has the required levels, however the underlying integer values may not relate correctly. You are probably better off assigning to z using `as.character` and then converting to factor.

eg

```
df$z <- as.factor( ifelse(is.na(df$y), as.character(df$x), as.character(df$y)) )
```

Comment: Dear Ricardo Saporta, thank you for taking the time to respond. I'm not sure how to implement your solution to arrive at the desired result. Could you expand don your example? Thanks, Eric

Comment: Thank you for expanding on your answer, the bottom line solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Eric, no problem.  Glad it helped!